# TypeScript interface for function with properties

Tags: angularjs, typescript, jasmine

I'm using TypeScript on an Angular.js project and testing with Jasmine.

When I mock a method on an object using `spyOn`, Jasmine replaces the method with a function that has a `calls` property so you can do, for instance, `thing.method.calls.count()`.

The problem is that the TypeScript compiler doesn't know about the `calls` property on the method and gives a compiler error:

```
property 'calls' does not exist on type '() => IPromise<IReport[]>'
```

How do I fix this error? Do I need to define a new interface that has a function signature as well as an object property? I've tried monkeying around with different interface configurations, but without luck so far.

Comment: Have you pulled in the jasmine.d.ts from the definitely typed repo?

Comment: Yes, I have the jasmine.d.ts referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I fix this error?

Basically add to the `Function` interface in a file like `globals.d.ts`. Demo:

```
interface Function {
    calls: any;
}

var foo = ()=>null;
foo.calls; // okay
```

This trick is covered here : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/lib.d.ts.html

Comment: I noticed you don't document how to acutally wire in a user-defined global.d.ts file.  Can you please elaborate?